# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a pomodoro clock for Freecodecamp. Everytime I execute the code with an specified value for the timer to do the countdown I do not encounter any problems. However when I try to modify the value for the countdown through the interface of the live demo-site the value is modified but for some reason I cannot see the result on the demo-site as before, if not that I encounter the following problem: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null ".

Javascript:

```js
function myfunction() {

       
    
      countdown((sessionTime * 60000) + Number(new Date()), ['hours','minutes', 'seconds'], function () {
        
        console.log('finished!');
        
      });
  
}


function lessBreakTime() {
  
  if(status == 0) {
    // Initial break time value.
    x = document.getElementById("breakTimeValue").innerHTML;
    // Substract break time with click.
    x -= 1;
    // Set the new break time if the timer has not reached -1.
    if (x >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("breakTimeValue").innerHTML = x;
      // Update break time value.
      breakTime = x;
    }
    
  } 
  
}

function moreBreakTime() {
  if(status == 0) {
    // Initial break time value.
    x = document.getElementById("breakTimeValue").innerHTML;
    // Get the string break value and set it as a numeric value.
    z = Number(x);
    // Add time to break
    z += 1;
    // Set the new break time value
    document.getElementById("breakTimeValue").innerHTML = z;
    // Update break time value.
    breakTime = z;
  }
}

function lessSessionTime() {
  if(status == 0) {
  // Inital session time value.
  x = document.getElementById("sessionTimeValue").innerHTML;
  // Substract one unit from the session time's value.
  x -= 1;
  // Set new session time if value is greater or equal zero.
    if (x >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("sessionTimeValue").innerHTML = x;
      // Update session time value.
      sessionTime = x;
      // Set timer value equal to session time.
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = x;
    }
  }
}

function moreSessionTime() {
  if(status == 0) {
    // Initial session time value.
    x = document.getElementById("sessionTimeValue").innerHTML;
    // Get the string session value and set it as a numeric value.
    z = Number(x);
    // Add time to break
    z += 1;
    // Set the new break time value
    document.getElementById("sessionTimeValue").innerHTML = z;
    // Update session time value.
    sessionTime = Number(z);
    // Set timer value equal to session time.
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = z;
    }
  
}

function checkStatus () {
  
  if(status == 0) {
    status = 1;
  } else {
    status = 0;
  }
}

var sessionTime = 30;
var breakTime = 5;
var status = 0;


var countdown = function (end, elements, callback) {
    var _second = 1000,
        _minute = _second * 60,
        _hour   = _minute * 60,
        _day    = _hour * 24,
        
        end = new Date(end),
        timer, 
        
        calculate = function () {
            
            var now = new Date(),
                remaining = end.getTime() - now.getTime(),
                data;
            
            if(isNaN(end)) {
                console.log('Invalid date/time');
                return;
            }
            
            if(remaining <= 0) {
            
                clearInterval(timer);
                
                if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback();
                } 
            
            } else {
            
                if(!timer) {
                    timer = setInterval(calculate, _second);
                }
                
                    data = {
                    'days': Math.floor(remaining / _day),
                    'hours': Math.floor((remaining % _day) / _hour),
                    'minutes': Math.floor((remaining % _hour) / _minute),
                    'seconds': Math.floor((remaining % _minute) / _second)
                    }       
            
                    if(elements.length) {

                        for(x in elements) {

                            var x = elements[x];
                            data[x] = ('00' + data[x]).slice(-2);
                            document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = data[x];

                        }
            
                    }
                
            }
                        
        };
    
    calculate();

}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="title" onclick="countdown()">Calvi's Pomodore Timer<h1>
 
    <div id="widgets">
      
      <div id="breakTime">
        
        <p>BREAK LENGTH</p>
        <div class="break"></div>
        <p class="minus" onclick="lessBreakTime()">-</p>
        <div id="sessionTimerDiv">
          <p id="breakTimeValue">5</p>
        </div>
        <p class="plus" onclick="moreBreakTime()">+</p>
        
      </div>
      
      <div id="sessionTime">  
       
        <p>SESSION TIME</p>
        <div class="break"></div>
        <p class="minus" onclick="lessSessionTime()">-</p>
        <div id="sessionTimerDiv">
          <p id="sessionTimeValue">25</p>
        </div>
        <p class="plus" onclick="moreSessionTime()">+</p>
        
      </div>
      
      <div id="timer">
        
        <div id="timerWatch" onclick="checkStatus(); myfunction()">
          <h3 id="status">Session<h3>
            <h4 id="time"><span id="hours"></span> <span id ="minutes"></span> <span id="seconds"></span></h4>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Is the javascript in the `<head>` or the `<body>` - and is it below or above the place where `<div id=breakTimeValue>` and `<div id=sessionTimeValue>` are?

Comment: @Mousey It shouldn't matter, since he's calling the functions from `onclick` attributes. So the functions can't be called until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: That error means that `document.getElementById()` can't find an element with the given ID. You need to look at what ID is being looked up, and figure out why it's not found.

Comment: Make you you convert any user-entered data to `Number`, `lessSessionTime` and `lessBreakTime` also do not call `Number(x)`,  but `moreSessionTime` and `moreBreakTime` do

Comment: I have already put my js code before the </body > tag and it doesn't do anything. Also, I know that the id it's not the problem because the code originally works with the original value for the session time. The problem occurs when I try to modify that value by interacting with the design and functionality of the prototype to check that the user can modify these values as they desire and that's when my code behaves weird.

Comment: @Mousey I already checked that. Javascript when subtracting a number from a string returns a number. When I  just let the code run with the value for the session set up on the code, it runs normal. When I click on the button to add more time to the session time, the value of that var is modified and it's a number. When I checked the console the error was occurring on my countdown function, specifically in the for loop: "document.getElemenyById(x).innerHTML = data[x];".

Comment: @Mousey have in mind that if I do not modify that value through the interface, I will not get that error.